# Reading 'nativeElement') on ngIf condition

Tags: angular, unit-testing

I have a div

```
<div *ngIf="activeTab == 0" >
<input id="test" >
</div>

<div *ngIf="activeTab == 1" >
<input id="test1" >
</div>
```

I will set tab on init as follows.

```
 ngOnInit(): void {
        this.setTab(0);
      }
    
      setTab(tabId: number): void{
        this.activeTab = tabId;
        if(this.activeTab == 1){
          this.getClientPortalLenderContacts();
        }else{
          this.getLenderList();
        }
      }
```

Now i need to get the element for unit test in div2.

```
it('search ', fakeAsync(() => {
          spyOn(component, "searchContacts").and.callThrough();
        component.activeTab = 1;
       
        let input = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#test1'));
        let el = input.nativeElement;
        el.value = 'Fake 2';
        el.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));
        
        expect(component.searchContacts).toHaveBeenCalled();
       
        flush();
      }));
```

But am getting error as

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'nativeElement')
```

please help me solve.

Comment: try adding a console.log just for `el` without accessing `nativeElement` and see if it is `null/undefined`

Comment: am getting null. I made activeTab as 1. But still it is  null is my issue.

Comment: In your test, execute `fixture.detectChanges()` before querying for element.

Comment: i tried fixture.detectChanges() as @JEWELJACOB. But am getting the same error